# how to define height of table in css dompdf

Tags: html, css, dompdf

I use dompdf to create a pdf.
On this pdf, i create a table. But I want to make this table still constant height like 500px;

This is the code:

```
 <div style="width : 100%; height: 550px">
                    <table class="detail" style="width : 100%; padding-top: -10px; height: 550px ">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th rowspan="2" style="width : 5%; border: 1px solid black"><strong>No</strong></th>
                                <th rowspan="2" style="width : 50%; border: 1px solid black"><strong>DESCRIPTION</strong></th>
                                <th colspan="2" style="border: 1px solid black"<strong>UNIT</strong></th>
                                <th rowspan="2" style="border: 1px solid black" colspan="2">Total<br> IDR</th>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td style='text-align : center; border: 1px solid black '><strong>QUANTITY</strong></td>
                                <td style='text-align : center; border: 1px solid black' ><strong>PRICE</strong></td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr><td style='text-align : center; border-right: solid 1px black; border-bottom : none; border-top:none'>1</td><td style='text-align : left; border-right: solid 1px black; border-bottom : none; border-top:none; padding: 2px;'>STORAGE</td><td style='text-align : center; border-right: solid 1px black; border-bottom : none; border-top:none; padding: 2px; '>1</td><td style='text-align : right; border-right: solid 1px black; border-bottom : none; border-top:none; padding: 2px;'>30,103,437.60</td><td colspan='2' style='text-align : right; border-right: solid 1px black; border-bottom : none; border-top:none; padding: 2px;'>30,103,437.60</td></tr><tr><td style='text-align : center; border-right: solid 1px black; border-bottom : none; border-top:none'>2</td><td style='text-align : left; border-right: solid 1px black; border-bottom : none; border-top:none; padding: 2px;'>REPO</td><td style='text-align : center; border-right: solid 1px black; border-bottom : none; border-top:none; padding: 2px; '>1</td><td style='text-align : right; border-right: solid 1px black; border-bottom : none; border-top:none; padding: 2px;'>1,470,852.00</td><td colspan='2' style='text-align : right; border-right: solid 1px black; border-bottom : none; border-top:none; padding: 2px;'>1,470,852.00</td></tr><tr><td style='text-align : center; border-right: solid 1px black; border-bottom : none; border-top:none'>3</td><td style='text-align : left; border-right: solid 1px black; border-bottom : none; border-top:none; padding: 2px;'>CLEANING</td><td style='text-align : center; border-right: solid 1px black; border-bottom : none; border-top:none; padding: 2px; '>1</td><td style='text-align : right; border-right: solid 1px black; border-bottom : none; border-top:none; padding: 2px;'>129,244,310.00</td><td colspan='2' style='text-align : right; border-right: solid 1px black; border-bottom : none; border-top:none; padding: 2px;'>129,244,310.00</td></tr><tr><td style='text-align : center; border-right: solid 1px black; border-bottom : none; border-top:none'>4</td><td style='text-align : left; border-right: solid 1px black; border-bottom : none; border-top:none; padding: 2px;'>ONE_BAR</td><td style='text-align : center; border-right: solid 1px black; border-bottom : none; border-top:none; padding: 2px; '>1</td><td style='text-align : right; border-right: solid 1px black; border-bottom : none; border-top:none; padding: 2px;'>20,591,928.00</td><td colspan='2' style='text-align : right; border-right: solid 1px black; border-bottom : none; border-top:none; padding: 2px;'>20,591,928.00</td></tr><tr><td style='text-align : center; border-right: solid 1px black; border-bottom : none; border-top:none'>5</td><td style='text-align : left; border-right: solid 1px black; border-bottom : none; border-top:none; padding: 2px;'>PERIODICAL TEST 2.5 YEARS</td><td style='text-align : center; border-right: solid 1px black; border-bottom : none; border-top:none; padding: 2px; '>1</td><td style='text-align : right; border-right: solid 1px black; border-bottom : none; border-top:none; padding: 2px;'>3,404,750.00</td><td colspan='2' style='text-align : right; border-right: solid 1px black; border-bottom : none; border-top:none; padding: 2px;'>3,404,750.00</td></tr><tr><td style='text-align : center; border-right: solid 1px black; border-bottom : none; border-top:none'>6</td><td style='text-align : left; border-right: solid 1px black; border-bottom : none; border-top:none; padding: 2px;'>PERIODICAL TEST 5 YEARS</td><td style='text-align : center; border-right: solid 1px black; border-bottom : none; border-top:none; padding: 2px; '>1</td><td style='text-align : right; border-right: solid 1px black; border-bottom : none; border-top:none; padding: 2px;'>7,354,260.00</td><td colspan='2' style='text-align : right; border-right: solid 1px black; border-bottom : none; border-top:none; padding: 2px;'>7,354,260.00</td></tr><tr><td style='text-align : center; border-right: solid 1px black; border-bottom : none; border-top:none'>7</td><td style='text-align : left; border-right: solid 1px black; border-bottom : none; border-top:none; padding: 2px;'>REPAIR</td><td style='text-align : center; border-right: solid 1px black; border-bottom : none; border-top:none; padding: 2px; '>1</td><td style='text-align : right; border-right: solid 1px black; border-bottom : none; border-top:none; padding: 2px;'>104,211,907.05</td><td colspan='2' style='text-align : right; border-right: solid 1px black; border-bottom : none; border-top:none; padding: 2px;'>104,211,907.05</td></tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td style='height : 50px;text-align : center; border-right: solid 1px black; border-bottom : solid 1px black; border-top:none'></td>
                                <td style='text-align : left; border-right: solid 1px black; border-bottom : solid 1px black; border-top:none; padding: 2px;'><strong>PERIODE MEI 2016 </strong></td>
                                <td style='text-align : left; border-right: solid 1px black; border-bottom : solid 1px black; border-top:none; padding: 2px;'></td>
                                <td style='text-align : left; border-right: solid 1px black; border-bottom : solid 1px black; border-top:none; padding: 2px;'></td>
                                <td colspan="2" style='text-align : right; border-right: solid 1px black; border-bottom : solid 1px black; border-top:none; padding: 2px;'></td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td rowspan="3" colspan="3" style="border : none;"></td>
                                <td style="text-align : right; border: 1px solid black"><strong>SUB TOTAL</strong></td>
                                <td colspan="2" style="text-align : right; border: 1px solid black">296,381,444.65</td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>

                                <td style="text-align : right; border: 1px solid black"><strong>VAT 10%</strong></td>
                                <td colspan="2" style="text-align : right; border: 1px solid black; ">
                                    29,638,144.47                                    </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>

                                <td style="text-align : right; border: 1px solid black"><strong>TOTAL</strong></td>
                                <td colspan="2" style="text-align : right; border: 1px solid black">
                                    326,019,589.12                                    </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
```

See in div and table height properties. I already declared it. So, if just one row in tbody, I wanna the table have constant height But this is not work in dompdf.

Please help, Any help it so appreciated.

Comment: Please share the code...

Comment: have you tried to give the `<table>` tag `display:block`?

Comment: Given that _"\[dompdf] will download and read external stylesheets, inline style tags, and the style attributes of individual HTML elements"_ you should _really_ get rid of all those duplicated inline `style="..."` and put them in a `<style>` block or better, in a stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

dompdf has some restrictions when it comes to tables. It is able to handle a defined width and distribute that as necessary in a fairly acceptable manner. But a defined height causes problems as dompdf does not know how to distribute the height across rows.

If you had a single row it would size the row correctly, but that's obviously not a solution for your problem.

There is no known work-around at this time.

Comment: I am facing the same problem now. I tried running my table code in codepen and adjusting the height randomly, it fits well with the data but using the same code in dompdf, the data "runs" away from the table whenever I add height to the table. Is this a problem with my code or with the pdf package?

Comment: Could really only say by looking at the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to specify 'px' for table widths and heights.

```
<table class="detail" style="width : 100%; padding-top: -10px; height: 550">
```

If the table is Dynamic, you might need some JS to add heights to all the rows.
3 Table rows = (550 / 3).
If the table is static, just do the maths yourself and add the height to each row. Without this height the table will form according to its contents.

Don't add width or height as an inline style. TABLE, TH's, TR's, and TD's have parameters for height and width. Remember to leave out "px"

Comment: Are you using jquery?

Comment: No, but I am understand a little bit about jquery